# Asp.net content place holder using javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, contentplaceholder, bxslider

I have a annoying issue involving javascript/jquery and asp:ContentPlaceHolders that I can't seem to solve and I've been trying all day.

I have an ASP.NET website with C#. The front page - Default.aspx, has a master page - MasterPage.master. I also have a control - bslider.ascx

I am trying to implement the image slider shown at http://bxslider.com/

The code in my control looks like this

```
<script src="../scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery.bxSlider.min.js" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#slider1').bxSlider();
    });    
</script>

<div id="slider1">
    <div>Slide one content</div>
    <div>Slide two content</div>
    <div>Slide three content</div>
    <div>And so on...</div>
</div>
```

The relevant code in Default.aspx is as follows:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" Runat="Server">
    <div class="sliderContainer">
        <uc4:BSlider ID="slider1" runat="server" />  
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

The relevant code in MasterPage.master is as follows:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="ContentContainer">
        <asp:contentplaceholder id="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">
            <uc3:headerLeft ID="Header2" runat="server" /> 
        </asp:contentplaceholder>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
```

However this does not work, it displays the content of the inner divs but one after another. I have tested this in a standard .html web page and it worked so it must be to do with the ASP.NET side of things.

Can anyone help with this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the script is executing properly?

Comment: Have you examined the HTML generated by viewing the page source?  Every so often, as you pointed out, the ASP.NET runtime generates the html in a way that's unexpected, and the only way to resolve the issue is to examine the resulting html generated and sent to the browser and lookig for something you wouldn't expect to see.

Comment: Well... what is doing this thing: `<uc4:BSlider ID="slider1" runat="server" />`? Just note that asp.net ID property will be different from what you have in aspx file. For instance, for ID="slider1" it could be like ContentPlaceHolder2_slider1 and this `$('#slider1')` will not find it.

Comment: Allesandro - as far as I know its executing properly, I've checked the developer consoles on chrome and firefox and they both check out ok.

Comment: FAngel - that code places the control (bslider.ascx) in the page. As for looking at the page source, it doesn't appear changed from the code I've shown you

Comment: well, is bxSlider available at all? I see jquery is taken from /scripts and bxslider - from /js. Does it really resides in /js? Aslo - do you have any scripts attached at all? And just note: use names like this: @JacobFrancis, otherwise user will not be notified (must be @ before user name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the problem! It was a conflict between the JQuery library and the BxSlider library.

It was fixed with the following code:

```
<script src="../scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery.bxSlider.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery.noConflict();
    $('#slider1').bxSlider();
});    
</script>
```

Kicking myself for not realising that it was a conflict issue. I hope this helps anyone else stuck in a similar situation to me.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that

```
<script src="../scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery.bxSlider.min.js" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#slider1').bxSlider();
    });    
</script>
```

is actually located in `<uc3:headerLeft ID="Header2" runat="server" />`, and if so you just have no scripts printed on a page.

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="ContentContainer">
        <asp:contentplaceholder id="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">
            <uc3:headerLeft ID="Header2" runat="server" /> 
        </asp:contentplaceholder>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
```

In code above, which is from master page, you defined a default content. It will be printed only if you have **no** `<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2"` in currently executed page. Try to simply move headerLeft outside contentplaceholder:

```
<div id="ContentContainer">
    <uc3:headerLeft ID="Header2" runat="server" /> 
    <asp:contentplaceholder id="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">

    </asp:contentplaceholder>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't do anything :(

Comment: Understand it like after you moved uc3:header outside content placeholder, nothing changed. Than - just as I asked in comment to question itself: are those files downloaded by browser(see network tab of developer console in chrome). Also - try to run  `$('#slider1').bxSlider();` directly in console and see what is printed out.

Comment: if I run the in the console, it comes out with TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'bxSlider'. So am I right in saying it can't find the object?

and yes both files are downloaded by the browser.

Comment: Welll... bxSlider file is NOT downloaded (or downloaded incorrectly). That is what that type error is saying.

Comment: strange as the filepath is definitely correct. The strange thing is it allows me to do simple jQuery stuff such as hovers

Comment: Hm. In network tab in Status column, for bxSlider - is there 200 OK or something else

Comment: its status is 304 not modified

Comment: What is your jquery version? bxSlider requires 1.3+

Comment: hm. Jquery 1.8.0 and bxSlider works perfect [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WDANA/) (bxSlider library is taken from its site, as shown in their example)

Comment: hmmm, must be something deep and obscure. I'll have a deeper look at it. Thank you for your continued help :)